# Checkbox doesn't display

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a checkbox that doesn't display correctly in MS Edge. I tried with meta tags.

My checkbox looks like this in Edge:

[image]

and like this in Chrome and Mozzila:

[image]

After all I don't really know what can I do.

HTML(Razor):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsPublic, new { @class = "flipswitch" })
```

My css:

```
    .flipswitch {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

    .flipswitch:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        display: block;
        line-height: 32px;
        width: 45%;
        height: 90%;
        background: #b11217;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        color: white;
        border: #888 1px solid;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .flipswitch:after {
        left: 2%;
        content: "OFF";
    }

    .flipswitch:checked:after {
        left: 53%;
        content: "ON";
    }
```

Comment: If you want to discuss a client-side problem, then please show client-side code. No one here wants to have to reproduce your server-side setup first, to see what `@Html.CheckBoxFor(…)` actually results in. [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

can you try add 'display: block' to '.flipswitch' class?

I mean:

```css
.flipswitch {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Can you share an image about this topic?

Comment: **I can't help you in this way.** I can't open this image.